# How to start iOS programming?

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm new to developing, currently only developed on web, like php,html,css,javascript etc etc. Any good tutorials on how to start programming?

Comment: try to search before creating new post. [how-to-articles-for-iphone-development-and-objective-c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939/how-to-articles-for-iphone-development-and-objective-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, this course is awesome:
http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/

The videos for the classes are online at iTunes U

http://itunes.apple.com/itunes-u/ipad-iphone-application-development/id473757255

It covers a lot of stuff, and has assignments to do so that you can start developing. First assignment will even walk you through the creation of your first iOS application.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Read everything you can on:

[Apple Developer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/index.html)